# Парсинг контактов предприятия с помощью регулярного выражения в PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день.

Есть такой SHTML-код:

```
 <div class="company_box">
                                    <h6>Контактные данные</h6>
                    <table class="short_details">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="det_lable">адрес:</td>
                            <td>Mielczarskiego 4/9<br/>
                                95-035 Ozorków                           (Озоркув)                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="det_lable">воеводство:</td>
                            <td>łódzkie</td>
                        </tr>

                                            <tr>
                            <td class="det_lable">сайт:</td>
                            <td>
                                                            <a href="http://www.pomocnadrogach.pl" onClick="trackOutboundLink(this, 'Company Outbound Links', 'www.pomocnadrogach.pl', 'Trans-Expert Tomasz Korczynski'); return false;">www.pomocnadrogach.pl</a>                        </td>
                        </tr>

                                            <tr>
                            <td class="det_lable">email:</td>
                            <td><a href="mailto:pomoc@pomocnadrogach.pl?subject=Zapytanie z Polsha24.com">pomoc@pomocnadrogach.pl</a></td>
                        </tr>
                                            <tr>
                            <td class="det_lable">тел:</td>
                            <td>+48 606808101</td>
                        </tr>
                                                                                        <tr>
                                <td class="det_lable">контакт:</td>
                                <td>Томаш Корчиньски</td>
                            </tr>
                                                                                </table>

                </div>
```

Мне нужно из этого кода извлечь данные: телефон Воеводтства, сайт, емейл, контакт.
Вот что я начал делать:

```
(адрес):(?(1)<[\w\W]+?<td>([\w\W]+?)<\/td>|)[\w\W]+?(воеводство):(?(3)[\w\W]+?<td>([\w\W]+?)<\/td>[\w\W]+?\/\/([\w\W]+?)")[\w\W]+?(email):(?(6)[\w\W]+?:([\w\W]+?)\?)
```

Для примера описал парсинг первых трех данных.

Найденные данные:

```
1.  [178-183]   `адрес`
2.  [218-328]   `Mielczarskiego 4/9<br/>
                            95-035 Ozorków                           (Озоркув)                        `
3.  [431-441]   `воеводство`
4.  [476-483]   `łódzkie`
5.  [719-740]   `www.pomocnadrogach.pl`
6.  [1054-1059] `email`
7.  [1110-1133] `pomoc@pomocnadrogach.pl`
```

Проблема такая: иногда бывает что порядок меняется или какие-то пункты есть, а в другом примере их нет. Можно как то условия задать не на "матч", а на имя. Или может есть какие-то другие варианты, чтобы удовлетворять данные условия.

Comment: Вам нужно взять произвольный парсер HTML и с его помощью реализовать требуемую логику.

Answer (score 3):

Вот [пример](http://ideone.com/lgU8Mk) на основе DOMDocument:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xpath->query('//tr');
$arr = array();
foreach($links as $link) { 
   $arr[] = array($link->getElementsByTagName("td")[0]->nodeValue, $link->getElementsByTagName("td")[1]->nodeValue);
}

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: ругается интерпретатор на Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array   на строчку $arr[] = array($link->getElementsByTagName("td")[0]->nodeValue, $link->getElementsByTagName("td")[1]->nodeValue);

Comment: Попробуйте сохранить ключи и значения отдельно, потом их можно объединить с помощью `array_combine ( array$keys , array $values)`.

Answer (score -1):

вобщем сделал я без X-path а именно
если че - контент выбираем только раз)))

```
$reg_addr = '/(?<=адрес):(<[\w\W]+?<td>([\w\W]+?)<\/td>|)/mi';
        preg_match_all( $reg_addr ,$content, $arr_addr);
        $reg_voevod = '/(?<=воеводство:)[\w\W]+?<\/tr>/mi';
        preg_match_all( $reg_voevod ,$content, $arr_voevod);
        $reg_site = '/(сайт):[\w\W]+?\/\/([\w\W]+?)"/mi';
        preg_match_all( $reg_site ,$content, $arr_site);
        $reg_email = '/(?<=email):[\w\W]+?mailto:([\w\W]+?)\?/mi';
        preg_match_all( $reg_email ,$content, $arr_email);
        $reg_phone = '/(?<=тел):[\w\W]+?<td>([\w\W]+?)<\/td>/mi';
        preg_match_all( $reg_phone ,$content, $arr_phone);
        $reg_fax = '/(?<=факс):[\w\W]+?<td>([\w\W]+?)<\/td>/mi';
        preg_match_all( $reg_fax ,$content, $arr_fax);
        $reg_time_work = '/(?<=время работы):[\w\W]+?<td><p([\w\W]+?)<\/p/mi';
        preg_match_all( $reg_time_work ,$content, $arr_time_work);
        $reg_facebook = '/(?<=время работы):[\w\W]+?<td>[\w\W]+?(facebook.com[\w\W]+?)"[\w\W]+?<\/td>/mi';
        preg_match_all( $reg_facebook ,$content, $arr_facebook);
        $reg_contact = '/(?<=контакт):[\w\W]+?<td>([\w\W]+?)<\/td>/mi';
        preg_match_all( $reg_contact ,$content, $arr_contact);

        $company_info = array();
        (!$arr_addr[1][0])?$company_info['addres'] = '' :     $company_info['addres'] = clear($arr_addr[1][0]);
        (!$arr_voevod[0][0])? $company_info['voevod'] = '' : $company_info['voevod'] = clear($arr_voevod[0][0]);
        (!$arr_site[2][0])? $company_info['site'] = '' : $company_info['site'] = $arr_site[2][0];
        (!$arr_email[1][0])? $company_info['email'] = '' : $company_info['email'] = $arr_email[1][0];
        (!$arr_phone[1][0])? $company_info['phone'] = '' : $company_info['phone'] = clear($arr_phone[1][0]);
        (!$arr_fax[1][0])? $company_info['fax'] = '' : $company_info['fax'] = $arr_fax[1][0];
        (!$arr_time_work[1][0])? $company_info['time_work'] = '' : $company_info['time_work'] = clear($arr_time_work[1][0]);
        (!$arr_facebook[1][0])? $company_info['facebook'] = '' : $company_info['facebook'] = $arr_facebook[1][0];
        $company_info['urlArray'] = $url;
        $company_info['source'] = 'www.primer-site.com';

        array_push($global_arr, $company_info);
        print "\n done  inner".$inner."and outer - >".$outer;
```

далее настакал массивов в json сохранил и можно делать что хош))

Comment: Это ад, вы же понимаете, сколько времени придется убить на исправление при малейшем расширении функционала или изменении верстки?

Comment: контент сохраняется в кеш, мне нужно было добавить одно поле после того как я спарсил, так "повторный парсинг" занял приблизительно минуту (9500 страничек);  В чем ад поясните?

Comment: @Etki я мало знаком из DOMXPath, подскажите пожалуйста если изменится верстка или функционал, DOMPath  будет продолжать корректно работать? Спасибо

Comment: Стопроцентной гарантии нет. Но представьте, что вам по какой-то причине необходимо добавить похожую, но не идентичную конструкцию в каждую ветку else.

Comment: if - проверяет наявность данных в массиве(если пусто то присваиваем пустую строку), если матчи присутсвуют то (else) ловим и записываем их в массив company_info.  Записано обьемная конструкция сдесь, можно тернарным оператором компакнее переписать чтобы было менее отпугивающее - но мне так удобнее.

Comment: @Etki переделал из тернарным))  в спорах рождается истина))  жду вашей конструктивной критики, Спасибо))

Comment: Хех. Все можно сделать во много раз проще. Исправьте регулярку Фейсбука.

Comment: @ReinRaus на этой штмл страничке есть несколько ссылок на facebook, если ее упростить то будут матчится и остальные. Так а как проще?))

Comment: Так посмотрите на нее и исправьте :-)

Comment: так все работает в поряде(уже в принцепе все спарсил), зачем же трогать то что работает?))

Comment: @IgorKalamurda `$reg_facebook = '/(?<=время работы):[\w\W]+?<td>[\w\W]+?(facebook.com[\w\W]+?)"[\w\W]+?<\/td>/mi';` как бы `время работы`

Comment: @ReinRaus все правильно написано. Посмотрите html  там где указаз facebook pastebin.com/X44FRvFS